# Adding a list to dataframe as element

Tags: r, list, dataframe, element, addition

I have a list:

```
mylist <- c("a","b","c")
mylist <- as.list(mylist)
```

and I have a Dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame("col1" = 1, "col2" = 2, "col3" = 3)
View(df)

  col1 col2 col3
1    1    2    3
```

How to add *mylist* as a new element in a new column *col4* in row number 1?

Expected output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    2    3 [a,b,c]
```

Is it event possible in R? I started learning R few days ago, I came from Pandas and it was possible there.

Comment: Try: `df$col4 <- list(unlist(mylist))`

Comment: Or `df$col4 <- list(mylist)`.

Comment: However, personally, I've never needed a list column in a data.frame.

Comment: Often it's not my decision what UI programmers need, but however, when I print the df after this, i get ->  new <list> <list [2]> how do I get values written in this list?

Comment: You get values with `df$col4[[1]]`